# scp <source>:<filepath> <dest> works from command line, but cp: cannot stat error from script. Why?

Tags: shell-script, scp

I am using scp to copy a file from a server to my computer. The command works fine when I type it from the command line, but when I try to make a script to do it, it fails with a "cp: cannot stat" error. It seems like the script is trying to check for the existence of a directory on my computer, when I do not intend it to do so.

I have a variable $LOGIN which equals user@server

**Here is the command that works on the command line:**

```
scp $LOGIN:dir/dir/file.txt .
```

**Here is what I have in the bash script:**

```
scp "$LOGIN:$1 $2"
```

**Here is how I call the script:**

```
./scriptname dir/dir/file.txt .
```

**And the error:**

> cp: cannot stat ':dir/dir/file.txt': No such file or directory

Any ideas on how to get this script to work?

Comment: Your quotes are incorrect.  `scp "$LOGIN:$1 $2"` should be `scp "$LOGIN:$1" "$2"`

Answer (score 3):

Because `LOGIN` was not exported as an environment variable, you lost it when you entered the script, so script tried to execute:

```
scp :dir/dir/file.txt .
```

instead of your desired:

```
scp user@server::dir/dir/file.txt .
```

The shortest "fix" would be to:

```
export LOGIN
```

before executing the script.

Note also that the quoting would be better as:

```
scp "$LOGIN":"$1" "$2"
```

so that `scp` sees two independent strings, not one.

Comment: Thanks Jeff that was it. I didn't realize scripts didn't have access to the  bash environment variables. That is weird.

Comment: there's a fine distinction between a shell variable and an *environment* variable

Comment: do take care with your variable names, too. People have been bitten using `PATH`, and there are others that are readonly or would change bash behavior in unexpected ways. Consider using lower-case variable names for your own data/purposes.